# DevExpress AspxSpreadsheet Open or Document.LoadDocument method is not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I need any point of view around this issue from any devexpress developer or anybody who could know about it.

I have this two methods:

The first one gets data from a cache variable and loads it into the spreadsheet document

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        documentId = (String)Session["id"];
        Spreadsheet.Open(documentId, DocumentFormat.Xlsx, () =>
                                            {
                                                return (byte[])Cache[documentId];
                                            });
        Cache.Remove(documentId);
        Session.Remove("id");
    }
}
```

And I have this other method for the Upload event where I get the data from the file and load it into the spreadsheet document

```
protected void UploadControl_FileUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsValid)
    {
        fileContent = e.UploadedFile.FileBytes;
        documentFormat = GetFileExtension(e.UploadedFile.FileName);
        documentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        if (documentFormat != DocumentFormat.Undefined)
        {
            Spreadsheet.Open(documentId, documentFormat, () =>
                                            {
                                                return fileContent;
                                            });
        }

    }
}
```

The Page_Load Spreadsheet.Open function works just fine.
The other one in UploadControl_FileUploadComplete doesn't.

The page does not postback or refresh after or before the upload event, but just comes through the UploadControl_FileUploadComplete event code and execute it.

Any comment or workaround on this will be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASPxUploadControl uploads files on callbacks. So, other controls can be updated on ASPxUploadControl's callback. You need to handle the client-side [FileUploadComplete](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientUploadControl_FileUploadCompletetopic) event and perform a callback on ASPxSpreadsheet to open an uploaded file. To perform a callback, use the [ASPxClientSpreadsheet.PerformCallback](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxSpreadsheetScriptsASPxClientSpreadsheet_PerformCallbacktopic) method. Then, on your server, handle the [ASPxSpreadsheet.Callback](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxSpreadsheetASPxSpreadsheet_Callbacktopic) event to open your document.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <dx:ASPxSpreadsheet ID="ASPxSpreadsheet1" ClientInstanceName="Spreadsheet1" runat="server" WorkDirectory="~/App_Data/WorkDirectory" OnCallback="ASPxSpreadsheet1_Callback"></dx:ASPxSpreadsheet>
        <dx:ASPxUploadControl ID="ASPxUploadControl1" runat="server" UploadMode="Auto" Width="280px" OnFileUploadComplete="ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete" ShowUploadButton="True">
            <ClientSideEvents FileUploadComplete="function(s, e) { OpenDocument(e.callbackData); }" />
        </dx:ASPxUploadControl>
    </div>
</form>


const string UploadDirectory = "~/UploadedFiles/";
protected void ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e) {
    if (e.IsValid) {
        string resultExtension = Path.GetExtension(e.UploadedFile.FileName);
        string resultFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName(), resultExtension);
        string resultFileUrl = UploadDirectory + resultFileName;
        string resultFilePath = MapPath(resultFileUrl);
        e.UploadedFile.SaveAs(resultFilePath);
        e.CallbackData = resultFilePath;
    }
}

protected void ASPxSpreadsheet1_Callback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.CallbackEventArgsBase e) {
    ASPxSpreadsheet1.Open(e.Parameter);
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenDocument(data) {
        debugger
        Spreadsheet1.PerformCallback(data);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer although I had mine already from devexpress website, and it was similar approach, basically the same. Here is their answer in case anybody else might need it: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T362124